# The conjugate closure of a subset is a kernel of a permutation representation associated to a group action

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
Let $A$ be the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$.
We know that $G$ can acts on $A$ by 
$$g\cdot xH=gxH.$$

For any $g\in G$, 
define that $\sigma_{g}:A\to A, \sigma_g(xH)=g\cdot xH$.
Then $\sigma_g$ is a permutation on $A$.

Let $S_A$ be the set of all permutation on $A$.
Define the permutation representation $\theta:G\to S_A$. 
Then $\theta$ is a homomorphism and 
$$\begin{align}
\ker{\theta}&=\text{core }H\\
&=\{g\in G\mid g\in aHa^{-1}\text{ for all }a\in G\}\\
&=\bigcap_{a\in G}aHa^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

The dual notion of the $\text{core}$ is the normal closure (or conjugate closure) of a subset $X$ of $G$.
Which is defined by 
$$\begin{align}
\bar{X}&=\langle \{gxg^{-1}\mid g\in G, x\in X\}\rangle\\
&=\bigcap_{X\subseteq N\lhd G}N.
\end{align}$$

Is there a group action whose kernel of the permutation representation is the normal closure $\bar{X}$ of $X$?

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: yes, just the action on the left cosets of the normal closure $\langle X^G\rangle$. For any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, the kernel of the action on the cosets of $N$ is $N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh! Thanks. You are right. But is there another group action whose kernel is the normal closure. I guess that mathematician find out some group action first. Then find out its kernel. That is, the normal closure. (May be my guess is wrong.)
Which book can I learn more about the theorem as you state: For any normal subgroup $N$... and related topic.

Comment: This is just Cayley's Theorem applied to $G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

*The following summarises the comment by @DerekHolt . . .*

Consider the action of the left cosets of the normal subgroup $\langle X^G\rangle$ generated by the action of $G$ on $X$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the kernel of the action of the cosets on $N$ is $N$.